# CSS gradient filter Javascript and IE 9

Tags: javascript, css

problem: **IE9**

I have a table. And i have a CSS class. The CSS class contains a gradient filter:

```
.red
{
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(sProperties);
}
```

if i do:

```
... <tr class="red"> ...
```

everthing works fine. If i do

```
<script type="javascript">

... element.className = 'red';

</script>
```

the filter doesnt apply. does anybody knows what event could be fired after assignment to apply? Doing td class="red" is no solution, the table is rendered with a powershell table helper. jQuery or other frameworks are also no solution, it would blow up this simple "one page" application. Thanks in advance, Robert

Edit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997(v=vs.85).aspx

```
object.style.filter =  "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(sProperties)"
```

Comment: Is the script called after `element` exists? E.g. in an `onload` or `ready` event, or somewhere after the element?

Comment: Yes the script container is on bottom the page.

Comment: [Works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/NVV63/).

Comment: @RobertP.: Are *you* testing the fiddle in IE9 and having it not work?

Comment: If it's not a table row, does it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `element` actually refers to the element you want to make red, and that the script calling it is called after `element` actually exists on the page, and that your CSS includes actual arguments to `Gradient` and not just the literal `sProperties`, then try zooming the page in and out to manually force a redraw. Assuming the gradient suddenly appears, try toggling the `display` of the `element` to hide and then show it again, thus forcing an automatic redraw.

Actually, that's a lot of assumptions... Maybe you should just use a `background-image` instead?

Comment: Setting class name will **always** trigger a reflow in IE. `elem.className = elem.className;` is one of the IE "features" (or hack?) to request a redraw.

Comment: @Kolink The display "hack" sounds good, i will try it - on Monday. If it's not working it's no problem, then i make the row simply red. background-color:red works fine, it's a problem with the gradient filter.

Comment: @RobertP. You have already tried: Notice that I said "setting `className`". It doesn't matter if the class changes or not, a reflow is triggered in IE.

Comment: @RobW Ok. If i do background-color:red everything works fine, I think it's an issue with the filter. I was thinking the second x = x assumption may solve the problem. Microsoft software behaves strange in many points ;-).

Comment: @RobertP. Can you provide a small demo in the question? That would be helpful to future readers, and I can quickly test and verify your observations.

Comment: @RobW I post the full sample on monday.